# declare a function at first and then define it later in R

Tags: r, function

I am new to R. Is it possible to declare a function at first and then define it later in R at RStudio ?

The function definition is long, I would like to declare it and then define it like:

```
f2 <- function()

fn <- function(a,b, c, d, q1)
{
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(d)
    print(q1)
    f2()   # originally, it is named as f1
}

x <- 6
y <- 10
z <- 58
v <- 20 
v1 <- 68 
fn(x,y , c=z, d=v, q1=v1)
f2 <- function()
{
   print("here is f2 definition")
}
```

I have change teh function name from f1 to f2, but, in debugger, the source viewer still jump to f1(), why ?

And, it is allowed to make a definition of f2 in this way ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear to me.  Since R is not compiled, changing the definition of a function that is called inside another function will have the expected effect.  If you run the code above (with some changes to make it work...) and then call `fn` again, it will use the new definition of `f2`.

Comment: Try running your code in a fresh R session.

Comment: @krlmlr, it cannot find f2() even if I run it in a new session. Thanks !

Comment: how can you not find f2? are you sure the above code is exactly what you run in your R session? I don't think so because if I run this code I have no problems in finding f2. (fn is fist defined within f2, so it isn't directly visible, but it is clear why).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get running your code:

```
> f2 <- function()
+ 
+ fn <- function(a,b, c, d, q1)
+ {
+     print(a)
+     print(b)
+     print(c)
+     print(d)
+     print(q1)
+     f2()   # originally, it is named as f1
+ }
> 
> f2()
> x <- 6
> y <- 10
> z <- 58
> v <- 20 
> v1 <- 68 
> fn(x,y , c=z, d=v, q1=v1)
Error: could not find function "fn"
```

Did you mean defining `fn` inside `f2`? If yes, then you don't have `fn` in your global environment, and trying to do `fn(x,y , c=z, d=v, q1=v1)` is pointless. If you don't understand why it happens that `fn` is defined inside `f2` and is not accessible from global environment, then I think the best recommendation is probably first to get a good book about R. What do you want to achieve?